# Can I have two "owned value objects" of the same class but configured in the DBContext to have two "Owners"?

Tags: entity-framework-core, c#-8.0, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have a class - say Address - that is used in the same Visual C# project by two different classes (say Customer and Order Billing Address).

I have the following in the DBContext.OnModelCreating():

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>.OwnsOne(a => a.HomeAddress);
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>.OwnsOne(a => a.BillingAddress);
```

When I try to create the migration I get the following error: "The type 'Address' cannot be configured as non-owned because an owned entity type with the same name already exists.".

I dont know what the issue is.  I want each address to be stored int eh entitiies db table.

I would like BillingAddress stored in the Order entity table and HomeAddress to be stored in the Customer table.

Comment: What you have shown is perfectly fine. The issue is caused by something you haven't shown - check your db context for `modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()` call.

Comment: If Order was a value object (no ID), and Customer also owned the Order would this work? </br>  modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>.OwnsOne(a => a.HomeAddress); modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>.OwnsOne(a => a.Order); modelBuilder.Entity<Order>.OwnsOne(a => a.BillingAddress);

Comment: Owned entities are configured only through the owner. In other words, you must use the builder returned by `OwnsOne`, e.g. `modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>.OwnsOne(a => a.Order).OwnsOne(a => a.BillingAddress);` Any attempt to use `modelBuilder.Entity<T>()` with owned type `T` will generate the exception in question.

Comment: When I do that then it creates a separate table for Address with Foreign Keys to Customer and Order and doesn't add Address to the Customer and Order Tables.  Is this correct?

Comment: All they should go to a single table if not specifically mapped to separate table. For instance calling `ToTable(...)`. Or having a loop like `foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.GetEntityTypes()) entityType.SetTableName(...);` - owned types must be excluded from such loops using `IsOwned()` method, e.g. `modelBuilder.GetEntityTypes().Where(t => !t.IsOwned())`. You seem to have a specific configuration issue, so if you want a concrete answer, post the minimal model/configuration which reproduces the issue, as well as the desired behavior.